# Editing Mendeley citations with Zotero

Tags: reference-managers

Elsevier have really really ruined Mendeley! The latest update has gone very disturbing, with lags, errors and citation taking too long. Mendeley Desktop was awesome! The new Mendeley is just very not worth the hassle.

Is there any way to edit a document's citations (cited with Mendeley Reference Manager 2.74) using Zotero? It used to work in documents cited with previous versions, but now I'm unable to get it edited with Zotero without re-citing everything.

I have already migrated all my libraries from Mendeley to Zotero and started using Zotero, but many documents I need to edit are cited with Mendeley. Also EndNote is an option if it would work with it.

Comment: I've got no horse in the game as far as Mendeley is concerned, but I don't see how the rant in the first paragraph is necessary. If it's deleted I'll change to an up vote.

Comment: Just to clarify, are these Word documents you're using to cite?

Comment: @CephBirk yes indeed Word document